# PhD Student, written my first paper. What are my next steps?

Tags: publications, phd, thesis

I have written a first paper for my Finance PhD. It is around 70 pages in length (double-spaced), possibly far to long.

What are my next steps?

How can I start the publication process?

Is there anything else I should do, or move onto the next paper immediately?

Comment: What does your advisor say on this? Have you asked him/her?

Comment: If to "How can I start the publication process?" their answer is "come up with some ideas", you need a different advisor. It's a clear procedural question with a clear procedural answer. It doesn't require ideas, only experience to answer.

Comment: @Roland I agree - but maybe the "come up with some ideas" part was more specific, as in "come up with ideas for journals where this would fit". Still not great, but maybe not quite as bad as it sounds.

Comment: I agree with Roland, this is not how an advisor should treat a new PhD student. Yes, he is right that you should get some ideas what to work on, but he should guide you into a direction what to look at. Like "have a look at topic X, there is this problem Y which is not exactly solved. See whether you can come up with something..." or somesuch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your advisor should judge whether your paper is worth publishing. If the answer is "yes", then go for it and follow the process outlined in the author's guide of the respective journal/conference/etc...

I don't know about the habits in finance, but a 70 pages paper sounds rather long. Maybe you should condense it (if possible / appropriate) before you ask your advisor. But it depends on the habits of your field (which you can learn by reading publications of others).

If your advisor has no answer for this question, go look for another position/advisor.

If they liked your work and ask for new ideas, you are on a good track - write down some proposals and ask for a discussion about the ideas.

Comment: _in my discipline (CS) no one would read (or write) a 70 pages paper_ — Not true.  70 double-spaced pages translates into 35 single-spaced pages, or even less if the journal uses smaller type.  I have several journal papers longer than that.

Comment: @JeffE well, CS is a huge field... I'll modify the answer a bit...